# awk to output table-like or excel-like columns in linux terminal?

Tags: bash, awk, terminal, multiple-columns

I do a long pipe, that ends with `...| awk '{print $5"\t\t" $3"\t"$4}'` in the Linux terminal. The columns are padded with tabs. The first column entries have different number of characters, so the second column results are not perfectly vertical. How to make the table look perfect?

[image]

Comment: Try awk's column alignment flags... try looking here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345429/how-do-i-print-some-text-in-bash-and-pad-it-with-spaces-to-a-certain-width

Answer (score 30, accepted):

try to pipe the result to column -t:

```
...| awk '{print $5"\t\t" $3"\t"$4}'|column -t
```

hope it helps

Comment: |column -t   helped =) Thank you!

Comment: +1 You could also use the `tabs` command, for example try setting a large tab size: `tabs 25`. Then run your pipe. If it's large enough you'll get the desired outcome. However, I prefer using `column -t`

Comment: If you are piping into `column`, you no longer need the double-tab following the first field (I assume that was to accomodate wide value in that field).

Comment: Expanding upon the comment @SuicidalSteve made, you can also use `| expand -t <number>` to convert tabs to spaces (once again, if it's large enough you'll get the desired outcome). I find this useful to look at in a text editor after the fact.

Comment: You can make it even simpler: awk '{print $5,$3,$4}'|column -t

Answer (score 6):

if your fields are tab separated the following one line script could print a table with cell borders

```
sed -e 's/\t/_|/g' table.txt |  column -t -s '_' | awk '1;!(NR%1){print "-----------------------------------------------------------------------";}'

Description            |value                 |Comment
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Internal               |322                   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
External               |42515                 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```