# Align a space delimited list with two variables in unix command line

Tags: unix, vim

I have a list that looks like this

```
Leslie Knope
Ron Swanson
Tom Haverford
Ann Perkins
April Ludgate
Andy Dwyer
Ben Wyatt
Chris Traeger
Jerry Gergich
Donna Meagle
Mark Brendanawicz
Craig Middlebrooks
```

I cannot change the structure of this list but I have to open it frequently in Unix and I would like to alias a command line vim/less command that will open the file like this:

```
Leslie   Knope
Ron      Swanson
Tom      Haverford
Ann      Perkins
April    Ludgate
Andy     Dwyer
Ben      Wyatt
Chris    Traeger
Jerry    Gergich
Donna    Meagle
Mark     Brendanawicz
Craig    Middlebrooks
```

Where the fields are aligned.

I think this could be done by greping the spaces to tabs and then piping the output to vim with a tab align option, although I have not been able to get this to work.

Comment: `column -t list.file | vim -`

Comment: `vim -mc '%s/ /&\t/' list.file`

Comment: Check this question & answer, it's infact a dup:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458729/awk-to-output-table-like-or-excel-like-columns-in-linux-terminal/12458844#12458844

Comment: @Kent: There are a few Vim-specific ways to do it too.  `:Tabularize` in particular is way more useful than the other solutions.

Comment: @lcd047 You are right, I am a vim user/(fan). There are indeed vim plugins can do auto-alignment.  However if it is `more useful than the other solutions` I cannot tell.  It depends on OP's opinion.  If I were him, and I just format and save the text, I won't open vim, fire command, and save. But if I need continue editing manually after formatting, vim is definitely the tool to go.

Comment: @Kent: My point is `:Tabularize` can do a lot more than align on spaces.  And you probably already knew that, too. :)

Comment: @lcd047 I am still using the old `Align` plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From within Vim, you can either pipe the list to `column -t`, as @Costas points out:

```viml
:%!column -t
```

Or you can install the [tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) plugin, put the cursor on the first line of the list, and run:

```viml
:Tabularize /\s
```

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty trivial if you have the Tabular plug in.

[image]