# Bash Indented Output for Multiple Variables

Tags: arrays, bash, printf, output, indentation

I have a script that loops over every text file in a directory, and stores the content in variables. The content can be anywhere from 1-50 characters long. The amount of text files is unknown. I would like to print the content in such a way that each variable falls into a clean column.

```
for file in $LIBPATH/*.txt; do
    name=$( awk 'FNR == 1 {print $0}' $file )
    height=$( awk 'FNR == 2 {print $0}' $file )
    weight=$( awk 'FNR == 3 {print $0}' $file )
    echo $name $height $weight
done
```

This code produces the output:

```
Avril Stewart 99 54
Sally Kinghorn 170 60
John Young 195 120
```

While the desired output is:

```
Avril Stewart  99  54
Sally Kinghorn 170 60
John Young     195 120
```

Thanks!

Comment: See: [How do I print some text in bash and pad it with spaces to a certain width?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6345429/3776858)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `printf`:

```
￼printf '%-20s %3s %3s\n' "$name" "$height" "$weight"
```

`%3s` ensures that all fields use three characters, `%-20s` does the same for 20 characters, but the `-` in front makes the output left-aligned.

If you want to limit the output to e.g. 20 characters, you can use

```
printf '%-20.20s %3s %3s\n' "$name" "$height" "$weight"
```

This will give you a left aligned minimum width of 20 characters and a maximum width of 20 characters, in other words it will ensure that you always have exactly 20 characters.

Comment: Thanks. If the name was longer than 20 characters, is there a way to truncate the name after the 20th character? I realize '%-.20s' would achieve this, but for names shorter than 20 characters, the indentation is lost.