# How to pad spaces of a certain width in a echo based output

Tags: bash, shell, padding

I would like to take expert advice to pad spaces of a certain width in an echo based output as I have below to make sure that the Columns are delimited with correct whitespace so, table output is useful for pretty-printing

**Below is Just an echo statement of a code:**

```
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
then
    echo -e  "$CurrntTime $MachineName   : SSH connection is Up"
elif [[ $? -eq 255 ]]
    then
    echo -e "$CurrntTime $MachineName   : SSH Authentication Failed"
```

**Produced Output:**

Below output as you see little distorted.

```
02/17/2021 23:56:15 myserver001   : SSH connection is Up
02/17/2021 23:56:15 myserver00101   : SSH connection is Up
```

**Desired Output:**

```
02/17/2021 23:56:15 myserver001     : SSH connection is Up
02/17/2021 23:56:15 myserver00101   : SSH connection is Up
```

Comment: Use `printf` instead of `echo` with field width

Comment: Why do you use option `-e`?

Comment: See: [How do I print some text in bash and pad it with spaces to a certain width?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6345429/3776858)

Comment: @Cyrus, thanks for the comment , I'll check this.

Comment: People voting on removal, [please read this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled/10844#10844). **Should duplicates be deleted?** In general, no: most duplicates stay around. Having multiple copies of the same question with different wording is useful as search fodder, because people looking for an answer may use different wording too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You may try this `printf` with `width=25` for 2nd field and `-` for left alignment:

```sh
printf "%s %-25s : %s\n" "$CurrntTime" "$MachineName" "SSH connection is Up"

# or
printf "%s %-25s : %s\n" "$CurrntTime" "$MachineName" "SSH Authentication Failed"
```